# how to write to a file while using java runnable jar using resurces

Tags: java

i im trying to write to a file -questions.json

[image: a busy cat]

.

```
 try (BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(myclass.class.getresurces("/Files/questions.json"));
```

but it gives me an error -

how can i do it ? * i am using Runnable jar java file

Answer (score 3):

You cannot write to resources within the resources folder in a jar file. you should use a regular file outside your jar. resources within jars are meant to be static resources that do not change.